# If statement isn't working while using dictionary or list

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a form with student ID and pages of slides that students have read.
Now I need to print out those students who read more than 200 slides and calculate how many of them. I've tried to import csv to list and dictionary.
I found it's not possible to use if and while loop as I learned in C language.

```
#1
import csv
f = open('student_example.csv','r')


for row in csv.reader(f):
     with open('student_example.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
         writer = csv.writer(outfile)
         [k,v] = row
         f[k] = v
         k = 0
         print (f[2])
         while k < 71:    #There are 71 students
            k += 1
            if f[k] >= 200:
                print (f[k])
#2
import csv

with open('student_example.csv', mode='r') as infile:
   reader = csv.reader(infile)

   with open('student_example_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
       writer = csv.writer(outfile)

       mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
       print(len(mydict))
       k = 200
       for rows[1] > k in reader:
            print(rows[1])
```

Sample output should be:
There are 13 students passed: dict_keys(['B046060035', 'B064020028', 'B064020052', 'B064030002', 'B065040041', 
'B066060019', 'B066090002', 'B073040038', 'B074020003', 'B074020024', 'B074020043', 'B074020053', 'B074020055'])

Answer (score 0):

Using your first try, you can do this in this way. 
You want to open you outfile and then iterate through the students.
check for each student how many slides they read and write to outfile if > 200

```
import csv
f = open('student_example.csv','r')

with open('student_example.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        [student_id, slides] = row
        if slides > 200:
            writer.writerow(student_id)
            print (student_id)
```